# Speed, Endurance, Pace off the Mark

Tags: running, endurance, running-training-plan, speed, sprinting

My main sport is field hockey. I really want to become a faster runner as well as improve my endurance and my pace off the mark.

What are some exercises/things I must do to achieve this? If anyone had a workout plan that would be much appreciated too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to a track that is the best place to increase your speed. Since you are mainly interested in quick bursts of speed you should concentrate on doing repeats and intervals. You could start with 100m repeats and even ladders where you do 2x100m, 1x200m, 1x400, 1x200, 2x100. You should do a 30 second recovery between each set.

The next exercise would be hills. Find a 400m hill (or short) and do 5x hill x 5 sets with a recover between each set.

Tempo runs will also help to increase your stamina.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to a track but I can still do it!